# Responsive Website Looks Completely Different on Desktop (using Developer Tools) vs. Android Chrome

Tags: android, html, css, wordpress, mobile

When I test out my website ([right here](https://www.bennettforoffice.org)) in Mozilla FireFox OR in Google Chrome using their developer tools to simulate a mobile device, they both look just fine! See this image:
[image: Desktop Example]

While the header is a bit too tall to my liking, at least I can scroll and view all of the "objects" on the page. However, when I try to go view the page on my Android Chrome browser itself, it looks completely different! See this image:
[image: Mobile Example]

There's no "objects" onscreen, I can't scroll down, it's almost as if only the header exists on the page! I have no idea how this is happening, nor how to fix it. What am I missing here, and how do I get my page to look the same on a mobile device as it looks in Responsive Design Mode? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. It's a Wordpress site under the hood, but I do have direct access to all of the files. I just don't know where to start!

Comment: I believe someone who knows AMP should answer your quistion.

Comment: Yep, you could also check the **AMP Plugins**, cause it's rendering [this page ?amp=1](https://bennettforoffice.org/?amp=1) for some reason.

Comment: Thanks HamiD and @maiakd , but what is "AMP"? Is rendering AMP = 1 a bad thing? Do I need it? If not, is it safe for me to disable it?

Comment: I disabled the AMP plugin in Wordpress, and now everything looks good on Android Chrome. Thanks @HamiD and maiakd, but do you know if I'm missing something important by disabling AMP?